# Using types in Styled Component in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components, react-typescript

So, I'm working with React Native and never used Styled Components before.
When I'm creating a new component without SC, such a custom button, I do the following:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps} from 'react-native'

import styles from './styles'

type CustomButtonProps = TouchableOpacityProps & {
  children: ReactNode 
}

const CustomButton = ({ children, ...props }: CustomButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} {...props}>
      {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export { CustomButton }
```

This way, when I'm using my component in other place, I can pass all aditional TouchableOpacity props that's not listed in my custom props.

I want to know what type I use to replace the `TouchableOpacityProps` when I'm using Styled Components to continue using the non-listed props, as, if I use `TouchableOpacityProps`, it gets me an error saying the types doesn't match:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'

import { StyledTouchableOpacity } from './styles'

type CustomButtonProps = ??? & {
  children: ReactNode 
}

const CustomButton = ({ children, ...props }: CustomButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledTouchableOpacity {...props}>
      {children}
    </StyledTouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export { CustomButton }
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your props is correct. I think you are using `styled.TouchableOpacity` where `TouchableOpacity` is provided by styled-component and it will prompt you error as it is not compatible with `react-native`'s `TouchableOpacity`

So providing the react-native TouchableOpacity to styled can solve the type problem:

```js
import { TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps} from 'react-native'

const StyledTouchableOpacity = styled(TouchableOpacity)`
  ...
`
```

---

Full Code:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityProps} from 'react-native'
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const StyledTouchableOpacity = styled(TouchableOpacity)`
  padding-vertical: 16px;
  padding-horizontal: 24px;
`;

type CustomButtonProps = TouchableOpacityProps & {
    children: ReactNode 
}

const CustomButton = ({ children, ...props }: CustomButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <StyledTouchableOpacity {...props}>
      {children}
    </StyledTouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export { CustomButton }
```